# Magmi import configurables don't associate simples

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, import, magmi

I'm using the magmi import tool for importing large products files. first I import the simples with this csv file:

```
websites,store,type,attribute_set,sku,name,meta_title,meta_description,image,small_image,thumbnail,image_label,small_image_label,thumbnail_label,price,description,categories,configurable_attributes,short_description,status,tax_class_id,visibility,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,maten,color,merk,geslacht
bedrijfskleding,bedrijfskleding,simple,bedrijfskleding,top_1,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,100% Drillkatoen. Velcro®-sluiting. 5 segmenten.,bedrijfskleding/B15_2013.jpg,bedrijfskleding/B15_2013.jpg,bedrijfskleding/B15_2013.jpg,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,4.02,100% Drillkatoen. Velcro®-sluiting. 5 segmenten.,[bedrijfskleding]/Petten & Accessoires,"maten,color",100% Drillkatoen. Velcro®-sluiting. 5 segmenten.,Enabled,Enabled,Enabled,Enabled,Enabled,Unic Size,White,Beechfield,mixte
bedrijfskleding,bedrijfskleding,simple,bedrijfskleding,top_2,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,100% Drillkatoen. Velcro®-sluiting. 5 segmenten.,bedrijfskleding/B15_2013.jpg,bedrijfskleding/B15_2013.jpg,bedrijfskleding/B15_2013.jpg,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,4.02,100% Drillkatoen. Velcro®-sluiting. 5 segmenten.,[bedrijfskleding]/Petten & Accessoires,"maten,color",100% Drillkatoen. Velcro®-sluiting. 5 segmenten.,Enabled,Enabled,Enabled,Enabled,Enabled,Unic Size,Black,Beechfield,mixte
bedrijfskleding,bedrijfskleding,simple,bedrijfskleding,top_3,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,100% Drillkatoen. Velcro®-sluiting. 5 segmenten.,bedrijfskleding/B15_2013.jpg,bedrijfskleding/B15_2013.jpg,bedrijfskleding/B15_2013.jpg,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,4.02,100% Drillkatoen. Velcro®-sluiting. 5 segmenten.,[bedrijfskleding]/Petten & Accessoires,"maten,color",100% Drillkatoen. Velcro®-sluiting. 5 segmenten.,Enabled,Enabled,Enabled,Enabled,Enabled,Unic Size,Bottle Green,Beechfield,mixte
```

Then after that I import the configurables with this file:

```
 websites,store,type,attribute_set,sku,name,simples_skus,configurable_attributes,meta_title,meta_description,image,small_image,thumbnail,image_label,small_image_label,thumbnail_label,price,description,categories,short_description,status,tax_class_id,visibility,is_in_stock
bedrijfskleding,bedrijfskleding,configurable,bedrijfskleding,topg_1,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,"top_1,top_2,top_3,top_4,top_5,top_6,top_7","maten,color",ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,100% Drillkatoen. Velcro�-sluiting. 5 segmenten.,bedrijfskleding/B15_2013.jpg,bedrijfskleding/B15_2013.jpg,bedrijfskleding/B15_2013.jpg,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,ULTIMATE - 5 SEGMENTEN,4.02,100% Drillkatoen. Velcro�-sluiting. 5 segmenten.,[bedrijfskleding]/Petten & Accessoires,100% Drillkatoen. Velcro�-sluiting. 5 segmenten.,Enabled,Enabled,Enabled,1
bedrijfskleding,bedrijfskleding,configurable,bedrijfskleding,topg_2,GRAND PRIX CAP,"top_8,top_9,top_10,top_11","maten,color",GRAND PRIX CAP,100% Twill katoen. Velcro� sluiting.,bedrijfskleding/B159_2013.jpg,bedrijfskleding/B159_2013.jpg,bedrijfskleding/B159_2013.jpg,GRAND PRIX CAP,GRAND PRIX CAP,GRAND PRIX CAP,6.72,100% Twill katoen. Velcro� sluiting.,[bedrijfskleding]/Petten & Accessoires,100% Twill katoen. Velcro� sluiting.,Enabled,Enabled,Enabled,1
bedrijfskleding,bedrijfskleding,configurable,bedrijfskleding,topg_3,BALL MARK GOLF CAP,"top_12,top_13,top_14","maten,color",BALL MARK GOLF CAP,100% chino katoen. Zweetband in 100% polyester. Cool Max SFP40+. Sluiting met gesp. Magneet op de klep om de bal aanduider te hechten.,bedrijfskleding/B185_2013.jpg,bedrijfskleding/B185_2013.jpg,bedrijfskleding/B185_2013.jpg,BALL MARK GOLF CAP,BALL MARK GOLF CAP,BALL MARK GOLF CAP,8.78,100% chino katoen. Zweetband in 100% polyester. Cool Max SFP40+. Sluiting met gesp. Magneet op de klep om de bal aanduider te hechten.,[bedrijfskleding]/Petten & Accessoires,100% chino katoen. Zweetband in 100% polyester. Cool Max SFP40+. Sluiting met gesp. Magneet op de klep om de bal aanduider te hechten.,Enabled,Enabled,Enabled,1
```

My configurable options for the configurable item proccessor are:

```
Perform simples/configurable link : Yes
auto match simples skus before configurable: No
Force simples visibility: Not visible individually
```

And the file get's imported without error's and
the simples are set to not visible individually. The configurable products are also created.
The only problem is that the configurable products don't have the simples associated after the import. Does anyone know what isn't correct? i've searched far and wide but just can't find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Hm. Can you confirm that the file is "UTF-8 without BOM" and that all simple products have values for all configurable attributes, and that there are no 2 simple products that have the same value-configuration?

Comment: Yes it is. Everything works except the associating. Even the simples that are under a configurable are set to not visible individually after import and the simples with no configurable are still visible.

Comment: Which magmi version are you using? Magento 1.9 should use at least 0.7.21 I think, maybe even better is 0.7.22_git

Comment: Also, "maten" and "color" are of type "dropdown", scope "global" and "use for config products = yes" in the backend?

Comment: I'm using 0.7.22_git and the attributes are made correctly. i've also noticed that the fields in table `catalog_product_relation` and `catalog_product_super_link` also get filled with right child and parent's id. really wondering why they don't show up at the backend and frontend(yes i've reindexed and cleaned cache) @simonthesorcerer

Comment: it was that the attribute wasn't used to create simples but configurables fixed it now at use for product types

Comment: k, you should post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the `configurable` and `simple` products in the same CSV for Magmi to associate them together in the Magento DB.  The `configurable` product goes immediately after the the `simple` products it is to be associated with.

You also need a `configurable_attributes` column to tell magmi which attributes will be configurable.

So it would be something like:

```
sku,type,configurable_attributes,size,color
011,simple,size,color,small,green
012,simple,size,color,large,green
013,simple,size,color,small,red
010,configurable,size,color
```

Of course, for the configurable product you do not put anything for size or color.

Also, I notice in your example code you have `"maten,color"` under `configurable_attributes`, I think this should be just `maten,color` without the quoute marks `""`.  I know this seems counter-intuitive for a CSV file but I remember getting tripped up by that when I was using Magmi and removing the quote marks solved it for me.

Comment: No, you don't need to have them in the same CSV file. Using multiple files works fine.

Comment: @simonthesouthsayer how do you associate configurable with simple products if they're not in the same csv file?

Comment: You can import the simple products first. Afterwards, you import the configurable products with the "simples_skus" column. I always did this because I hate columns that are useless for some rows :) and you would have those with "configurable_attributes", "simples_skus" and the attribute-columns for the simple products.

Comment: The extra quotation marks are there because i viewed it with notepad. in the original csv there aren't quotation marks but they get added automatically because it's csv with separator comma

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `super_attribute_pricing` column in your csv use like below

```
super_attribute_pricing
```

where value for this column per product like `color::white:0;black:0;blue:0`

in above value color = configurable attribute to build your products and after 2 colon first is value for configurable option and after 1 column its difference of price if any.

Try this way to build your configurable product. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: this isn't a required column right? If i don't use it it should use the default

Comment: Attribute Pricing
Magento allows you to apply different prices to different items in a configurable product. For example, the base product might be $20 – but the XXL size might be $1 more ($21). To provide alternate prices in your import create a column called "super_attribute_pricing".

The simple products do not need a value in this column. Configurable products that do not change prices based on the attributes do not need a value in this column either.

Comment: i think you given wrong configurable product attribute use only `color `instead of `maten,color`

Comment: you should be able to use 2 configurable attributes @liyakat since "maten" is translated to "sizes". and size and color should both be configurable for my simple products

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case was just a misconfiguration in my file Magmi_ConfigurableItemProcessor.conf. I changed it to

```
[Magmi_ConfigurableItemProcessor]
CFGR:simplesbeforeconf = "1"
CFGR:updsimplevis = "0"
CFGR:nolink = "0"
```

And it worked fine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Had a very similar issue, turned out the attribute values were being stored with the wrong Store ID, since if I go into one product and just change the value and save then it would work, so I found that when magmi imported the values it inserted them into the database with store id 1.
I thus manually changed them directly in the db back to 0 after not finding any other place to do this.

I only changed it for the attributes I need to connect to configurable products. Here is the sql:
        `UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int SET store_id=0 WHERE attribute_id = {{attribute_id}} AND store_id = 1;`

If you have already manually saved one attribute value, then it will exist in both store 1 and 0, thus giving you an sql error. Manually delete the row with store id 1 by searching the combination of attribute_id and entity_id.